# Split Dataframe based on list items in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to split a dataframe based on list items in a column

```
               Name     Currency_Pair
0         Currency1     [ccy_UK_GBX=Minor, ccy_UK_USD=Foreign]
1         Currency2     []
2         Currency3     [ccy_UK_GBP=Major]
4         Currency4     []
```

Output Dataframe:

```
               Name     Country CCY     Denom
0         Currency1     UK      GBX     Minor
1         Currency1     UK      USD     Foreign
2         Currency2     NaN     NaN     NaN
3         Currency3     UK      GBP     Major
4         Currency4     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Pandas [explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [series.str.split()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) seem like a good place to start

Comment: I was trying to use melt because explode was giving an Attribute error. I realized that explode is only available pandas>=0.25. Ended up updating my conda to get it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider `df`:

```
In [238]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Currency1', 'Currency2', 'Currency3', 'Currency4'], 'Currency_Pair':[['ccy_UK_GBX=Minor', 'ccy_UK_USD=Foreign'], [], ['ccy_UK_GBP=Major'], []]})

In [239]: df
Out[239]: 
        Name                           Currency_Pair
0  Currency1  [ccy_UK_GBX=Minor, ccy_UK_USD=Foreign]
1  Currency2                                      []
2  Currency3                      [ccy_UK_GBP=Major]
3  Currency4                                      []
```

Use [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
In [242]: df = df.explode('Currency_Pair')

In [244]: df['Country'] = df.Currency_Pair.str.split('_').str[1]

In [245]: df['CCY'] = df.Currency_Pair.str.split('_').str[2].str.split('=').str[0]

In [246]: df['Denom'] = df.Currency_Pair.str.split('=').str[-1]

In [247]: df
Out[247]: 
        Name       Currency_Pair Country  CCY    Denom
0  Currency1    ccy_UK_GBX=Minor      UK  GBX    Minor
0  Currency1  ccy_UK_USD=Foreign      UK  USD  Foreign
1  Currency2                 NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
2  Currency3    ccy_UK_GBP=Major      UK  GBP    Major
3  Currency4                 NaN     NaN  NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Good answer +1, I think expand=True would be helpful

Comment: Thanks @ansev .  `expand=True` would not create much of a difference, as I will still have to do operations and multiple splits on all columns.

Comment: @ansev,@Mayank - Explode is only available pandas >= 0.25. Thanks, updated my pandas and it works.

Answer (score 1):

#### [`Series.str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with **`'_|='`** and **`expand=True`**

```
df2 = df.explode('Currency_Pair').reset_index(drop=True)
new_df = (df2.join(df2['Currency_Pair'].str.split('_|=', expand=True)
                                       .loc[:, 1:]
                                       .set_axis(['Country', 'CCY', 'Denom'],  
                                                 axis=1))
             .drop('Currency_Pair', axis=1))
```

**Output**

```
print(new_df)

        Name Country  CCY    Denom
0  Currency1      UK  GBX    Minor
1  Currency1      UK  USD  Foreign
2  Currency2     NaN  NaN      NaN
3  Currency3      UK  GBP    Major
4  Currency4     NaN  NaN      NaN
```